# How can I have xlsxwriter write backslashes in number format (for LibreOffice)?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Snippet to reproduce:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
data_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format':  r"0.00##\%;[RED](0.00##\%)"})
worksheet.write('A1', 5.5, data_fmt)

workbook.close()
```

My expecatation would be that when I open up that file and inspect the format for `A1` it would be `0.00##\%;[RED](0.00##\%)`.

Instead I get `0.00##%;[RED](0.00##%)`

NOTE: The format, taken from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806849/number-format-in-excel-showing-value-without-multiplying-with-100) is what would give you the percent sign at the end without multiplying the value by 100.

---

EDIT2:

```
>>> import xlsxwriter
>>> xlsxwriter.__version__
'1.0.2'
```

Also, I am opening the file in LibreOffice.

---

EDIT3:

Here's a snippet that tries 1, 2, 3, and 4 backslashes. All of them produce the same format when I open the result in libreoffice.

```
import xlsxwriter

fmts = [r"0.00##\%;[RED](0.00##\%)", r"0.00##\\%;[RED](0.00##\\%)",
        r"0.00##\\\%;[RED](0.00##\\\%)", r"0.00##\\\\%;[RED](0.00##\\\\%)"]
fp = "test{}.xlsx"
for i, fmt in enumerate(fmts):
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(fp.format(i))
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    data_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format': fmt})
    worksheet.write('A1', 5.5, data_fmt)
    workbook.close()
```

---

EDIT 4:

I have confirmed that this is issue does not exist in excel. So currently it is strictly a LibreOffice issue.

Comment: So is this a question? And what is your question? What output is produced by that, and what do you want?

Comment: sorry, I accidentally hit submit before I was done. Full question now up

Comment: Oh lol okay :) :P

Answer (score 2):

Format is as you have desired.  Are you checking under custom by right clicking the A1 cell?

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I am using LibreOffice, and when I had a coworker open it up in excel, he also saw `5.5%`. So it's a libre-office specfic thing.

NOTE: When i directly paste in that format-string while already inside LibreOffice, I get the desired effect

Comment: It may be LibreOffice thing. Try double back slashes \\  instead of single infront of % and see if helps.

Comment: @micheal_j_ward Try the suggestion to use double (escaped) backslashes. That's how Excel stores them internally. Excel doesn't strictly require them to be escaped but other applications, such as LibreOffice, might.

Comment: @jmcnamara and Anil_M, I updated the question with a new snippet that tests 1, 2, 3, and 4 backslashes. All of them produce the same format string when inspected in excel (that produces the `550%` instead of `5.5%`)

Comment: Actually, I was wrong about the backslashes. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your program works as expected with Excel. Here is the output when I ran it:

[image]

Also I created a new file in Excel, entered 5.5 and your format (`0.00##\%;[Red]\(0.00##\%\)`), saved it, and verified the format as it is written by Excel:

```
$ unzip percent.xlsx -d percent

$ xmllint --format percent/xl/styles.xml | grep -i red
<numFmt numFmtId="164" formatCode="0.00##\%;[Red]\(0.00##\%\)"/>
```

As you can see there is a slight difference with backslashes for the brackets but nothing that would change how Excel would display the number:

```
0.00##\%;[RED](0.00##\%)    # Input
0.00##\%;[Red]\(0.00##\%\)  # Saved by Excel
```

So I would guess that this is a LibreOffice issue. You could verify that by creating a file with the format you want in Excel, saving it, and then opening it in LibreOffice.