# Change the format of numbers in Excel

Tags: excel

I have two sets of data that I want to load into a separate Excel sheet. One set is shown as percentage (as I want It to be shown), and the other is shown in numbers, see example below. Changing the dataset 1 to percentage shows huge percentages.

Does anyone know how to convert the numbers so the two sets of data are shown as a percentage?

```
    Dataset 1   Dataset2
1   0.950000    0,96%
2   0.400000    0,40%
3   1050000,00  1,05%
4   0.400000    0,40%
5   0.020000    0,20%
```

Comment: Are you sure your example is correct? 0.95 => 0.96% and 1050000 => 1.05%?

Comment: Yes you are write, but has something to do with . and ,
When I press the % button it 1050000 becomes 1050000%, not 1.05%.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806849/number-format-in-excel-showing-value-without-multiplying-with-100), credits to @AxGryndr

Select Dataset1 range and apply custom format:

```
0,00##\%
```

Or

```
0.00##\%
```

Depending if your system uses a dot or comma.